# C function code in malloc'd memory

Tags: c, memory, heap-memory

Is there a way to malloc memory space and then copy function code inside the space in C?

This question might not make sense in practice. I ask this question out of curiosity so that I can get a better understanding about how c and its underlying implementation work.

Here's the follow-up questions if it is possible to copy the code into heap:

1. How to determine the size for the function binary code when copy?
2. Can we use function pointer to execute the code? (the code is placed inside malloc'd memory, and that part of memory might be marked as non-executable for safety reason, but I'm not sure about this)

Comment: Nope. C++ doesn't work this way. Now, what is the real problem you're trying to solve. No, not the one about putting a function into the heap, but the real problem whose solution you believe involves putting a function into heap.

Comment: For questions about C/C++ use the "C/C++" tag. To spare you the time searching: there is no such tag because ther is no language C/C++. And the languages C and C++ are very different languages. Pikc the one you intend to use, remove the unrelated tag!

Comment: And there is no heap or segments in either language. These are implementation details. You have to choose at which abstraction layer you ask. And you cannot convert a function pointer to a `void *`.

Comment: In a specific environment with a specific compiler, you might succeed in hacking totally undefined behaviors to execute code on the heap. Except, perhaps, for the thrill of getting it to work, this would be a useless exercise.

Comment: @Olaf Thank you very much for your suggestions. I have edited the question to make it less confusing. As for the void* type, I didn't intend to use it as function pointer.

Comment: @YifanHao: YOu use a function pointer for a `void *`! What do you think `memcpy` takes? It is not even guaranteed `memcpy` can access the code-space!

Comment: @Olaf I know the standard doesn't allow mixing code pointer and function pointer, but I cannot think of a way to malloc memory and then assign it to be function pointer.

Comment: What do you really want to do? Please **edit your question** to improve it and motivate it (and tell what is your application, and on which computer and operating system).

Comment: Looks actually like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). You really need to motivate and improve your question. If your goal is to generate new functions at runtime, my answer explains how to do that (on most PC with a real OS).

Comment: Supporting @BasileStarynkevitch: **What is your actual problem you try to solve**? If that is some academic question, you have to add more information. If oyu have a practical problem, you most likeyl use the wronmg approach. Either way, you have to provide more information.

Comment: I deleted the code snippet, which might be the source of confusion.

Answer (score 3):

This (or something like it) is possible on most machines, but the techniques you'd use are system-specific -- there's no standard C or C++ way to do it.

Even figuring out the length of a function so you can copy it is difficult.  I don't think you can do it reliably if the function is in the same translation unit, because the compiler may have done optimization magic that you can't see.  However, if the function is in a different file, then the interface to it will probably be more reliable (although there could be linker magic going on that you would have to understand and emulate to accomplish your goal.)

Other problems (on some systems) are that malloc'd memory may not be executable.  (This is often the case to improve security by preventing execution of code placed in an overrun buffer area.)  However, systems with executable protection often have an alternate memory allocation function that can give you a chunk of memory where executable code can be placed, and to which execution can transfer.  Some variation of this feature is necessary to implement shared libraries.

Finally, although *self modifying code* is probably the first thing people probably think of when considering your question, a reasonable, legitimate use of the relevant techniques might be in a native-code, just-in-time compilation system.

You may get better answers by specifying a particular OS and CPU where you want to do this.

Comment: Another legitimate use arises in some microcontrollers, where CPU access to RAM is faster than access to Flash.  If you need a function to run quickly, you might copy it to RAM and then use a function pointer to transfer control there, rather than to the copy in Flash.

Comment: This invokes UB in the first place and will most likely not work on modern full-size OS do to No eXecute and other security features. Let alone missing relocation, etc. WRT MCUs: this depends on the system, but typically this is done by the startup code or special system functions. Often the function have to be compiled with special options for this. Anyway, on a desktop this is strongly discouraged and shold not even be considered (JIT compilers are a special subject, but the above is apparently none).

Comment: Here is a 2011 example for Linux: it allocates memory using `mmap` and requests that it be marked executable.  Then it copies some instruction codes to the memory, transfers control there via a function pointer, and prints out the result.  http://burnttoys.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-allocate-executable-memory-on.html  As @Olaf states, the casting of the memory pointer to a function pointer is sketchy and requires investigation to see whether it will work on any particular machine.

Comment: I don't know if it's technically UB (I am not a C/C++-standard expert) but there must be a reliable way to perform this operation on any OS, since it is an operation that any OS must be able to perform if it is to load an executable from secondary storage and commence execution.

Comment: An OS can use assembly language and e.g. compiler extensions. This is about application software, which is not an OS. Reading and understanding the standard is vital if you answer questions about standard behaviour. I'd strongly recommend it!

Answer (score 2):

The C standard (e.g. [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)), read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) or the C++ one (e.g. C++11, C++14 and notice that they have [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function); read more about [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) ...) does not define what is a function address or pointer (it only defines what calling such an address does, then function pointers should point to *existing* functions and there is no *standard* way to build new ones dynamically at runtime). In some systems (pure [Harvard architectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture)) a function sits in a different address space than the C heap (and on these systems executing anything in `malloc`-ed heap makes no sense and is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)). so the C11 standard forbids casting function pointers to data pointers and vice-versa.

So, to your question

> Is there a way to malloc memory space and then put function code inside the space in C?

the answer is **NO** in general (but on *some* systems you could generate code at runtime, see below).

However, on desktop or laptop PCs or server PCs or tablets (running common OSes like Linux, Windows, MacOSX, Android), you usually have a [Von Neumann architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture) and there is (for a given [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing))) a single [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) sharing both code and data (notably heap data obtained with `malloc`). That virtual address space organised in [pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory)), and each page has its own [memory protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection). Read more about [computer architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_architecture), [instruction sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set), [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit)s. Quite often heap allocated data is non-executable thru the [NX bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit).

The [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) plays an essential role. You need to read an entire book about OS, such as [*Operating Systems : Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/).

<sup>(I am guessing that you want to "create" some new functions in your program at runtime and call them thru C function pointers; you should explain why; I suppose you are coding some application for a PC or a tablet with a Unix-like OS, practically a Linux-x86_64 distribution, but you could adapt my answer to Windows)</sup>

You could use some libraries for [JIT compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) such as [asmjit](https://github.com/asmjit/asmjit), [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/), [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) (or [libjit](https://www.gnu.org/software/libjit/) or GNU [lightning](https://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/)) and they generate code which is executable.

You could also use dynamic [loading techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) on some [plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)); on POSIX systems look into [dlopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlopen.html) & [dlsym](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlsym.html) (which can be used to "create" function addresses from a loaded plugin, beyond what the C11 standard allows). A possible way would be to generate some C code in a temporary file, compile it into a plugin, and `dlopen` that generated plugin. See [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/303123/40065) for more details.

On Linux, you can use the [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and related [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (used to implement [`malloc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) in your [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library), and also by [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)) to change your virtual address space, and the [mprotect(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html) system call to change protection (on a page by page basis). So if you want to explicitly copy or generate some *function code* it has to go into an executable page (`PROT_EXEC`).

Notice that because of [relocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_(computing)) issues (and [offsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_(computer_science)) or absolute addresses in machine code), it is not easy to copy machine code. Copying with `memcpy` the bytes of a given function code into some executable page usually won't work without pain: often `CALL` or `JUMP` [machine instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code) are using *PC-relative* addressing, so copying them without changing their offset won't work.

> if it is possible to copy the code into heap

No, **it is not possible** in general; and in practice it is much more difficult than what you believe (even on Linux-x86_64, where other approaches that I mentioned are preferable); if you want to go that route you need to care about low level implementation details (instruction set, processor, compiler, [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention), [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)s, relocation) and your code would be non-portable and brittle.

> How to determine the size for the function binary code when copy?

That question (and the notion of function size) has **no sense** in general. Some optimizing compilers are able to emit some machine code which is *shared* between *several* C functions, or to emit *several* non-contiguous machine code chunks for a given function (and `gcc -O2` is likely to do these optimizations, read about [function cloning](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2009-10/msg00279.html)). On Linux you could use [dladdr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr.3.html) (or the `nm` or `readelf` programs) to get a "symbol size" in the [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) sense, but that size might not mean much. And as I explained, you can't just byte-copy binary machine code, you need to relocate (some parts of) it.

Comment: Modern CPUs use an interal Harvard architecture with a univied external address space. Differentiation is done by the MMU, memory and cache subsystem. In addition modern OS seperates code and data address space, so it is not that straight forward. Some embedded architectures which outnumber in pieces sold x86 and ARM together, two of them are AVR and PIC, also use Harvard architecture. Even for smaller MCUs, copying from Flash to RAM is not easily archievable, e.g. due to memory encryption..

Comment: The application code sees a unified virtual address space with a Von Neumann architecture.

Comment: That does not mean code can be copied to data space, less the copy excecuted. It is not that simple like Harvard **or** Von Neumann today. Converting a function pointer to `void *` is undefined behaviour for good reasons. It has the bad smell of an XY problem. On a full-featured OS there is no use in this, even if we ignore all other problems.

Comment: I agree and I did told that in my answer (last paragraph)

Comment: I don't only refer to relocation.One of the other issues are the caches. At least you might need barriers and flushing/reloading the instruction cache. And many more.

Comment: Notice however that `dlsym` is *very often* used with a cast (from its `void*` result) to a function pointer, and on Linux it is useful to use `dladdr` on function pointers casted to `void*`

Comment: Might be; I did not say it is impossible. But the question does not even give a hint about the platform. So we have to argume with the standard only. (Btw: the standard explicitly mentions casting a function pointer to/from `void *` as a common extension).

Comment: No (I don't argue about C standard only), my answer explicitly mentions some Unix-like OS on PC, practically Linux on x86-64. I do know (and did wrote in the first paragraph) that casting function pointer to data address is nonsense in general (in the pure C11 standard)

Comment: "No" to what ?? (And why would one want to do this on x64/Linux where the code is actually in the same RAM type as the data? That does not make sense.

Comment: RAM is irrelevant for application code (only virtual address space matters) on Linux. What does not make sense?

Comment: RAM is very well relevant. You copy code finally to RAM with `memcpy` (and I hope we can agree that `malloc` yields an address space which is eventually mapped to RAM for accesses on x86 systems) to make it run faster or for other hardware-specific reasons like writing the Flash on an MCU, but that is nothing you do in a Linux-**application**. But maybe you thought about more "esoteric" hardware like magnetic bubbles or cores.

Comment: No, a Linux application runs in virtual memory. Some pages won't be in RAM. [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)) can happen, and the kernel does handle a lot of memory exceptions (in its implementation of VM)

Comment: I insist, from an application point of view RAM is irrelevant. Every application on my Linux desktop is running in virtual memory and has its own virtual address space. An application developer cares only about that virtual address space, not about RAM (only [mlock(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html) is relevant for RAM) and I sometimes run a process with an address space slightly bigger than my RAM